# WPF - ProgressBar Updates only until the process is done

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I am trying to use the ProgressBar, that is new for me (only asynchronous possible?)

I followed the [WPF-Tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/), and meet no problem. I just put the code here again for comodity.

```
public partial class ProgressBarTaskOnWorkerThread : Window
{
    public ProgressBarTaskOnWorkerThread()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

So I just took and used that code, and there is no problem with it.
Now, I am trying to use it in my code, and just modified the `worker_DoWork` function as following :

```
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (this.ValueProgress < 100)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(this.valueProgress);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
```

In my code I import a list of files, so I set this.ValueProgress to 0, then everytime I import a file, I do this.ValueProgress=100*NumberImportedFiles / TotalFiles;

I also noticed, in debug, that my `worker_ProgressChanged` function is not working while importing (but `worker_DoWork` is working fine). Then only when all the files are imported, `worker_ProgressChanged` is launched many times(seems it is just firing all the changes that has been done at once).

Edit : Just made another "stupid" test :

I kept the original code, adding a condition, so the ProgressBar will begin moving after I edit ValueProgress :

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(this.ValueProgress==0)
        {
            i--;
        }
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

And that code is not working neither, I mean, the function `worker_DoWork` is working correctly, i begins to increment after the process is begun, but the ProgressBar is not moving(worker_ProgressChanged not firing).

Comment: Print the value of this.valueProgress just before ReportProgress - Is it changing/Increasing?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava yes it is

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava thanks, in fact the problem was I didn't understand how BackgroundWorker works. After Arc2006 answer I could understand it reading another tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to comment so I'm posting an answer. If some of my assumptions are mistaken I apologize in advance. Where are you setting the value of ValueProgress? If you are setting the value of the ValueProgress on the UI thread instead of using the background work then you may be holding up the UI thread.

If that is the case then any updates to the progress bar will not show up. Try doing any updates in the background worker to keep the UI free to update.

Here is the [link](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/multi-threading-with-the-backgroundworker/) of tutorial that will help to solve the issue

Comment: So you're right, I didn't save ValueProgress in the background work, could you just explain how to do that please? (never used asynchronous functions until now).

Comment: Just found a tutorial about `BackgroundWorker`, will first read it then, thanks already I think I understood what you meant

Comment: Traditionally, when you start a background worker all the code that is changing values should be put in the method you assigned to worker.DoWork -- in this case worker_DoWork. You can change values outside of worker threads, but the UI will not reflect the changes until after all the code finishes executing.

Comment: yes I now understand that reading tutorial (still on it), honestly for now I don't understand what you mean, but after reading tutorial I guess I will, doesn't seem that difficult

Comment: so if I understood the tutorial, all the code (importing files) may not be in my UI, but in `worker_DoWork` function? ProgessBar may be managed only in Asynchronous?

Comment: That is correct. You are able to put any code you want in the UI thread, but while the code is executing the UI will not refresh and will appear frozen until your code finishes). By placing your code (importing files) in a worker thread you leave the UI free to update. Progress bars are generally used when you have a long task to do, so they are often updated using the pattern shown in the tutorial.

Comment: ok, will validate your answer cause this is the one who helped me to find it, just will add the link of tutorial, very useful for who will meet the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to update the ProgressBar on the main thread.

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Issue is that updating UI on another thread is not going to work. Only the main thread can.